# Tone sweep from array of frequencies with python

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I have array with frequency values and want to generate wav file with tone that sweeps between given values. Say

```
freqs = [100, 100, 200, 400, 1000, 100, 50]
duration = 7
```

I want WAV with duration of 7 seconds. So from T=0 to T=1s tone should be 100Hz, from T=1 to T=2 sweeps from 100Hz to 200Hz and so on.

How do I generate waveform to pass to scipy.io.wavfile.write?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [Lukasz Tracewski said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68472399/3317803) this can be done with [np.chirp()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

duration = 30 
Fs = 16000
freqs = [100, 100, 300, 300, 600, 100, 100]

segment = int(Fs * duration /  (len(freqs)-1))
f = np.array(freqs) / Fs
wav = np.array(1)
for f0, f1 in zip(f[:-1], f[1:]):
    wav = np.append(wav, chirp(np.arange(segment), f0=f0, t1=segment, f1=f1))

write('test.wav', Fs, wav)
```

This gives nice spectrogram:
[image: nice spectrogram]
Listen here: https://soundcloud.com/dcoder_mm/npchip/s-Kx8L2vN0nfv

It works, but you can notice (on the spectra and while listening) some clicky noise.

Let's try with lower frequencies:

```
freqs = [100, 100, 300, 300, 600, 100, 100]
```

[image: not so nice spectrogram]
Listen here: https://soundcloud.com/dcoder_mm/dj-npchirp-feat-low-frequencies/s-fNsA61bJ0Wk

Things gets much worse. Why?

Because of phase error at the points where two chirps combined:
[image: phase error]
[image]
[image]

To get rid of this, we need to calculate phase correction. As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear) phase at the last point (for the **linear** chirp!) would be:

phi = T*(f1+f0)/2

So this will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

duration = 30 
Fs = 16000
freqs = [100, 100.5, 99, 99.3, 100.1, 100]

segment = int(Fs * duration / (len(freqs)-1))
f = np.array(freqs) / Fs
wav = np.array(1)

phase = 0
for f0, f1 in zip(f[:-1], f[1:]):
    wav = np.append(wav, chirp(np.arange(segment), f0=f0, t1=segment, f1=f1, phi=phase))
    phase = phase + 360*(segment*(f0+f1)/2)

write('test3.wav', Fs, wav)
```

[image: niiiice spectra]
Listen: https://soundcloud.com/dcoder_mm/dj-npchirp-feat-low-frequencies-phase-c/s-XneSWRlojLD

**Note that phi = T*(f1+f0)/2 suitable only for linear chirp. For other methods you need different phase formula.** Also see [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30245/clicks-at-end-of-chirp-signal)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do this for two arbitrary frequencies:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import chirp
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

interval_length = 1 # in seconds
fs = 16000 # sampling of your signal
f0 = 100   # frequency 1
f1 = 200   # frequency 2
t = np.linspace(0, interval_length, int(fs * interval_length))
w = chirp(t, f0=f0, f1=f0, t1=interval_length, method='linear') # check also other methods
write('test.wav', fs, w)
```

I leave as an exercise for you to do this in a loop for the set of frequencies that you have.

Comment: I am not a python developer however I am impressed scipy.signal has a frequency sweep synthesizer very cool  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html

Comment: Yes, but there's a problem when frequencies almost the same (say 100Hz and 100.5Hz): combining chirps would lead to phase error and noise at the point of stitching

Comment: @user3317803 I think the effect will be barely noticeable, you can always smooth out the stitching point.

Comment: @dcoder_mm Did you give it a try? If you encountered artifacts or other problems post the code and results.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Yes, and I encountered phase mismatch which leads to wide-spectrum noise on stitching points (sounds like clicks). I believe best solution would be calculation phase shift and apply it via the *phi* parameter of chirp(). I'll revisit this project in a couple of days and post results here